# Rest Calls fail in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, restsharp

I try to pull some data from a REST API and get it into MS SQL Server.
For debugging purposes I prepared everything in a C# console app, and it workes fine.

Now I copied my code to an SSIS Script task and I cant seem get a connection to the service.
It compiles, but upon execution I get a null response with an error (it does not throw an exception, the error is what´s in the response object):

```
IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("SomeURL");

restRequest.AddParameter("login", "Someuser");

IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Get(restRequest);
```

The Debugger tells me the following when I inspect the response object:

```
Status = SendFailure
Message = "Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.."
StackTrace = "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at RestSharp.Http.<ExecuteRequest>g__GetRawResponse|181_1(WebRequest request)\r\n   at RestSharp.Http.ExecuteRequest(String httpMethod, Action`1 prepareRequest)"
```

Using Visual Studio 2019 with RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json Libraries.
I also have a SOAP-Client script task in the same SSIS Project and that one works.

Edit: I tried as @KeithL suggested, using webClient and I basically get the same error.

Comment: I almost always use a webclient found in namespace System.Net; External dlls are hardto work with in SSIS. If you have basic JSON to deserialize, I'd also recommend using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

Comment: Unfortunately the JSON part is not so trivial. For example it requires some complex report configuration to send and returns a pretty complex structure with dynamic fields and all. So I´d rather not do it all "by foot". Currently I use the console app, which I call from SSIS to write to csv and then import that. 
Still, after getting around the whole install dll to gac hurdles and getting it to compile, I feel like I´m 90% there. Still thank you for your answer!

Comment: I definitely shift to console app if I want to use Nuget for Json. I like Quicktype at https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp for class building of complex Json classes

Answer (score 2):

Using webClient...

EDIT: Sometimes you need to specify this in your code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

   System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
   wc.Headers.Add("login", "Someuser");
   string json = wc.DownloadString("SomeUrl");
```

Comment: I tried this, I basically get the same error: $exception {"Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.."} System.Net.WebException

Comment: @Daniel Sometimes you have to add the 2 service point manager clauses.